# Placing fields on a Webform in edit mode - Sharepoint - HTML - JS

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

I am currently working on a configuration of a webform on Sharepoint and am having the difficulty were I cannot have one field next to the other (side by side) when the form is in Edit mode:

In Edit mode

[image]

If I save the form, I am able to see the correct display:

Non edit mode

[image]

However, I wanted to have the form in Edit mode display the fields one next to the other (side by side).

Ex:

```
"text"+"dropdown"+"text"+"freetextfield", etc.. (side by side)
```

and not:

```
 "text"+"dropdown"                  (under)
 "text"+"freetextfield"
```

I am using the below code:

```
<tr>
<td class="ms-formlabel" colspan="4" style="padding: 0px;">
<p>Text goes here <span bfeId="isaCustomChoiceYesNo03" bfeType="field" class="ms-formbody" bfeWidth="100"> </span>More text goes here<span bfeId="isaCustomChoice09" bfeType="field" class="ms-formbody" bfeWidth="200"> </span> </p>
</td> 
</tr>
```

How this can be achieved? Am I using the correct statement (`<p></p>`) to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML space codeword `&nbsp;` to replace the spaces that appear between fields in the code , using this way , can achieve display side-by-side display of fields in Webform Edit mode.

Here is an example that will achieve this feature.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="ms-formlabel" colspan="4" style="padding: 0px;">
<p>Text goes here <span bfeId="isaCustomChoiceYesNo03" bfeType="field" class="ms-formbody" bfeWidth="100"> </span>More text goes here<span bfeId="isaCustomChoice09" bfeType="field" class="ms-formbody" bfeWidth="200"> </span> </p>
</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @RaytheonXie-MSFT. Thank you for the response. Unfortunately with the above provided code, I get the same display i edit mode.  Any further ideias? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try to add “<table></table>” tag before “<tr></tr>” tag.
I have updated the answer